# Iterate through collection in collection until last element in Java

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class SimpleEntity {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean closed;
    private List<SimpleEntity > simpleEntityChildren;
}
```

I want to iterate recursively into `SimpleEntityChildren` until the last element and I don't know how to implement it.

```
public void iterator(SimpleEntity simpleEntity ){
    simpleEntity .forEach(entity-> {
        if(!entity.getSimpleEntityChildren.isEmpty()){
            entity.forEach(secondEntity-> {
                if(!secondEntity.getSimpleEntityChildren.isEmpty()){
                    //and so on to the last element
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use recursive methods.

Comment: Just add a method to `SimpleEntity` and call _that_.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to check if the list is empty before iterating over it. Iterating over an empty list will simply do nothing.

Comment: "*I want to iterate recursively*" - that sounds like a contradiction in and of itself. If you want to iterate, why not use an interative (i.e. `for`-) loop? Or is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterate through recursive objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436080/iterate-through-recursive-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a recursive call:

```
public void iterate(SimpleEntity entity) {
    // you might want to add some logic here, that actually does something
    // with the current SimpleEntity instance you are iterating over
    for (SimpleEntity child : entity.getSimpleEntityChildren()) {
        iterate(child);
    }
}
```

Note that this can lead to infinite recursion and `StackOverflowError` if there are cycles in the graph of all the `SimpleEntity` instances.

As Boris commented, you can pass to the method a `Consumer<SimpleEntity>`, that would contain the logic to be performed on each `SimpleEntity` instance.

```
public void iterate(SimpleEntity entity, Consumer<SimpleEntity> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(entity);
    for (SimpleEntity child : entity.getSimpleEntityChildren()) {
        iterate(child,consumer);
    }
}
```

For example, you can recursively print the names of all the `SimpleEntity` instances in the hierarchy of a given `SimpleEntity` instance:

```
SimpleEntity someEntity = ...
iterate(someEntity, e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
```

You can also add a non recursive method to start the iteration process:

```
public void iterate(Consumer<SimpleEntity> consumer) {
    iterate(this,consumer);
}
```

Now you can write:

```
SimpleEntity someEntity = ...
someEntity.iterate(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
```

Comment: Maybe add a `Consumer<SimpleEntity>` to the method signature? Also worth pointing out that this is a DFS.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that's a good idea. It will make this method more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive methods.

```
public void iterator(SimpleEntity simpleEntity ){
 simpleEntity .forEach(entity-> {        
        iterator(entity);        
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be:
1. **Change your main class to**:

```
public class SimpleEntity {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean closed;
    private List<SimpleEntity > simpleEntityChildren;

    public Stream<Tree> flattened() {
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(this),
                simpleEntityChildren.stream().flatMap(Tree::flattened));
    }
}
```

2. **Then simply iterate over it like:**

```
public void iterator(SimpleEntity simpleEntity) {
        simpleEntity.flattened().forEach(entity->{
            // Do whatever you want
        });
    }
```